# memorystream copyto network stream issues

Tags: c#, networking, memorystream, networkstream, binaryformatter

I'm having a problem with this code here.

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    bf.Serialize(ms,SerializableClassOfDoom);
    ms.Position = 0;
    byte[] messsize = BitConverter.GetBytes(ms.Length);
    ms.Write(messsize, 0, messsize.Length);
    NetworkStream ns = Sock.GetStream();
    ms.CopyTo(ns);
    //ms.Close();
}
```

I can't figure out what's happening here, or why it's not working. It seems like eather it doesn't copy, or it closes the network stream, or something.

I'm sorry, I've tried debugging it, but if anyone can see any obvious problem here, I would appreciate it.

By the way, the class serializes fine, and the MemoryStream contains the data, but for some reason doing a ms.CopyTo(ns) just doesn't seem to work?

Essentially what I want to do is serialize the class to the network stream, with the size of the serialized data preceding it. If someone has a better way to do this let me know!

Comment: my guess is that after you leave the using block the NetworkStream is disposed because it runs out of scope. you can try to Flush it before the end of the using block. Or is your problem somewhere else?

Comment: Tried flushing both the memorystream and the networkstream before the Using ends, that didn't seem to do it either.

Comment: You need another `ms.Position = 0;` after `ms.Write`. Edit: Actually that first `ms.Position = 0;` seems wrong as you are overwriting data you just wrote.

Comment: @leppie Omg, feel stupid. I was just thinking it would shift the data that's there forward(for some reason), but instead, you're right, it's just overwriting what was already written. That has to be the problem.

Comment: @kelton52: I'll add answer, just in case :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are resetting the stream position at the wrong time.

In your case, you write the 'length' to the beginning of the stream.

The following should work:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    bf.Serialize(ms,SerializableClassOfDoom);
    byte[] messsize = BitConverter.GetBytes(ms.Length);
    ms.Write(messsize, 0, messsize.Length);
    ms.Position = 0;
    NetworkStream ns = Sock.GetStream();
    ms.CopyTo(ns);
}
```

**Update:**

For writing 'length' to the start, use a temporary stream/byte[].

Example:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    bf.Serialize(ms,SerializableClassOfDoom);
    byte[] data = ms.ToArray();
    byte[] messsize = BitConverter.GetBytes(ms.Length);
    ms.Position = 0;
    ms.Write(messsize, 0, messsize.Length);
    ms.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    ms.Position = 0; // again!
    NetworkStream ns = Sock.GetStream();
    ms.CopyTo(ns);
}
```

**Update 2:**

More efficient way.

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    bf.Serialize(ms,SerializableClassOfDoom);
    byte[] messsize = BitConverter.GetBytes(ms.Length);
    NetworkStream ns = Sock.GetStream();
    ns.Write(messsize, 0, messsize.Length);
    ms.Position = 0; // not sure if needed, doc for CopyTo unclear
    ms.CopyTo(ns); 
}
```

Comment: I want the message size to be at the beginning of the stream, is this going to work? It seems like this would toss it behind the data.

Comment: I'm sorry, again lack of details. That's essentially the code I started with, but I wanted to rewrite it so I didn't have to have any arrays outside of messsize. I'm trying to do this really fast, and data is over 1mb every time(for lan connections). I was hoping I could manipulate the streams in a way that would save me from having to drop the stream into an array, which was the most expensive call.

Comment: @kelton52: using 2 memorystreams would probably be the way to go then, alternatively, do NOT use `Stream.CopyTo`. I'll update answer (again).

Comment: Yeah Update 2 is what I just came up with, but why do you say not to use Stream.CopyTo?

Comment: @kelton52: Due to lack of unambiguous documentation. See comment for setting the position. After all, underneath it simply does `Stream.Read` and `Stream.Write`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to rewind the memory stream to the beginning before calling CopyTo (use ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Start))

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a real problem but i see a litte refactoring issue here.

Try using

```
Stream.Flush()
Stream.Close()
```

before finishing any Stream.

Also surround it with `try-catch` statements like this, to ensure closing and flushing happens even if there is an exception!

```
Stream s = new Stream();
try{
    s.Write();
}catch(Exception ex){
    //Oh god, we are doomed!
}finally{
    s.Flush();
    s.Close();
}
```

Your code would look like

```
NetworkStream ns = null;
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    try{
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        bf.Serialize(ms,SerializableClassOfDoom);
        ms.Position = 0;
        byte[] messsize = BitConverter.GetBytes(ms.Length);
        ms.Write(messsize, 0, messsize.Length);
        ns = Sock.GetStream();
        ms.CopyTo(ns);
        //ms.Close();
    }catch(Exception ex){
        throw;
    }finally{
        ms.Flush();
        if(ns != null)
            ns.Flush();

        ms.Close();
    }
}
```

After this you should be able to find your problem.

Comment: Two things I see wrong with that, the ns doesn't resolve to the finally block. Also, I don't want to close the network stream. I'll modify it and give it a shot though.

Comment: Updated with ns outside and no close.

Comment: That's fine, I probably didn't give enough details or something.