# Having problems sending a bitmap over the network using TCP

Tags: c#, networking, bitmap

I'm trying to set up a simple desktop monitoring program in C#. I've been searching around for almost an hour trying to find a working model, however anything I found either threw exceptions or was too darn complicated, making calls to obscure functions.

I am able to capture the screen to a bitmap instance and I have had a crack at trying to send it, but at the moment, the programs run normally and close. The client throws an exception because the connection wasn't closed properly (lazy me!), but nothing else happens. No output file is written to, nothing.

Here is the server's code

```
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System;

class ScreenCapture
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            TcpListener srv = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 51530);
            srv.Start(1);
            TcpClient client = srv.AcceptTcpClient();
            NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();
            StreamWriter send = new StreamWriter(ns);
            StreamReader read = new StreamReader(ns);

            Rectangle screenshot;
            Bitmap bitmap;
            screenshot = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea;
            bitmap = new Bitmap(screenshot.Width, screenshot.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
            g.CopyFromScreen(screenshot.Left, screenshot.Top, 0, 0, screenshot.Size);
            g.Dispose();
            MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream();
            bitmap.Save(m, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

            byte[] data = m.ToArray();
            Console.WriteLine(data.ToString());
            send.Write(m);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the client's code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

class RetrieveScreenShot
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 51530);
            NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();
            Image receivedImage = Image.FromStream(ns);
            receivedImage.Save("output.bmp");
            ns.Close();
            client.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well for one, even if it was working, you've got the wrong file extension. `ImageFormat.Jpeg` would, to me, imply `output.jpg`. That aside, the only other thing that I see is `send.Write(m);` might be better as `send.Write(data);`

Comment: It doesn't really matter at the moment, as I'm still testing things. I can still view the photo no matter what extension it has. Giving send.Write(data); a try now.

Comment: And I guess try closing the connection properly and wrapping `TcpClient` in a using block, at least on the server side (to get rid of that exception).

Comment: Tried sending "data" instead of "m" and it still did the same thing. I'll change the TcpClient to a using

Answer (score 1):

```
try
{
   TcpListener srv = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 51530);
   srv.Start(1);
   TcpClient client = srv.AcceptTcpClient();
   NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();

   Rectangle screenshot;
   Bitmap bitmap;
   screenshot = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea;
   bitmap = new Bitmap(screenshot.Width, screenshot.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
   Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
   g.CopyFromScreen(screenshot.Left, screenshot.Top, 0, 0, screenshot.Size);
   g.Dispose();

   MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream();

   //you can also just save to network stream and skip the copy but i kept it for demo
   bitmap.Save(m, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

   //reset the memory stream to start of stream
   m.Position = 0;
   //copy memory stream to network stream
   m.CopyTo(ns);
   //make sure copy is completed
   m.Flush();
   m.Close();

   //Makes sure everything is sent before closing it
   ns.Flush();

   //The Image.FromStream() seems to wait for the stream to be finished/closed.
   client.Close();

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
   Console.ReadKey();
}
```

The code on the Receiver side did not change much just the file extension.

The following answers help to explain the changes:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8308142/1698182

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22906136/1698182