# Image.FromStream using networkStream

Tags: c#, image, sockets

I'm trying to use the method `FromStream` of the class `Image` to set an image received by a tcp connection using a network stream.
Here there are the two sides code:

Server:

```
TcpListener server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 34567);
server.Start();

TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
byte[] buffer = new byte[256];

int n = 0;
Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, n), client.Client.RemoteEndPoint);
byte[] img = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\Luca\Desktop\video grest\8599929-nessun-segnale.jpg");
client.Client.Send(img);
```

Client:

```
TcpClient tcp = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 34567);
NetworkStream stream = tcp.GetStream();
MessageBox.Show("fatto");
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);
```

The problem is that the client program stops on the last instruction and it doesn't go forward, and if close the server (even 30 minutes later) it says the connection was closed but the picturebox doesn't show anything... Why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see the same behavior that you described - for me, the server exits immediately after the Send() call.  At that point, the client says that the connection was closed.  I was able to fix the issue by having the server call client.Close() after the Send().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your client code

```
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);
```

is expecting for the stream to be ended before processing the image.

So you should close the socket server-side using:

```
client.Close();
```

just after:

```
client.Client.Send(img);
```